# TypeError in React Hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

## What I Want to do

Using Next.js, we aim to implement a button called 'ConnectMetamask' that, when pressed, will launch the prepared hooks and store the value in a variable called 'userSigner'.
this is 'src/hooks/UserSigner.js'

## Problem

When I press the `ConnectMetamask` button, then appear this error message

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
TypeError: (0 , _hooks_UserSigner__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_7__.useUserSigner) is not a function
```

so, In my implementation, is it not possible to call useUserSigner as a function?

## What I Did

The code in 'src/hooks/UserSigner.js' that implements the hook looks like this

```
import { useMemo, useState } from "react";

const useUserSigner = (injectedProvider, localProvider) => {
  const [signer, setSigner] = useState();
  useMemo(() => {
    if (injectedProvider) {
      console.log(" Using injected provider");
      const injectedSigner = injectedProvider._isProvider
        ? injectedProvider.getSigner()
        : injectedProvider;
      setSigner(injectedSigner);
    } else if (!localProvider) setSigner();
    else {
      if (
        window.location.pathname &&
        window.location.pathname.indexOf("/pk") >= 0
      ) {
        const incomingPK = window.location.hash.replace("#", "");
        let rawPK;
        if (incomingPK.length === 64 || incomingPK.length === 66) {
          console.log(" Incoming Private Key...");
          rawPK = incomingPK;
          window.history.pushState({}, "", "/");
          const currentPrivateKey =
            window.localStorage.getItem("metaPrivateKey");
          if (currentPrivateKey && currentPrivateKey !== rawPK) {
            window.localStorage.setItem(
              "metaPrivateKey_backup" + Date.now(),
              currentPrivateKey
            );
          }
          window.localStorage.setItem("metaPrivateKey", rawPK);
        }
      }
    }
  }, [injectedProvider, localProvider]);
  return signer;
};
export default useUserSigner;
```

And the page that calls it, 'src/pages/components/CoenectWallet.jsx', will look like this

```
import { useState } from "react";
import {  ethers } from 'ethers'
import ConnectMetamaskButton from '../components/ConnectMetamaskButton';
import { useUserSigner } from "../../hooks/UserSigner";
import detectEthereumProvider from '@metamask/detect-provider';


export default function ConnectWallet(props) {

    const [Accounts, setAccounts] = useState("Connect Metamask");

    const [injectedProvider, setInjectedProvider] = useState();
    console.log("injectedProvider", injectedProvider);

    const ethersProvider = ethers.getDefaultProvider("ropsten");
    console.log("ethersProvider = ", ethersProvider);

    async function ConnectMetamask() {
        try {
            const newAccounts = await ethereum.request({
                method: 'eth_requestAccounts',
            })

            let accounts = newAccounts;
            setAccounts(accounts[0]);
            console.log("Accounts = ", Accounts);

        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
        }
        getBalases();

        const provider = await detectEthereumProvider();
        console.log("provider = ", provider);

        setInjectedProvider(new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(provider));
        console.log("injectedProvider = ", injectedProvider);

        const userSigner = useUserSigner(injectedProvider, ethersProvider);
        console.log("userSigner = ", userSigner);
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <header className="text-gray-100 bg-gray-900 body-font shadow w-full">
                <div className="container mx-auto flex flex-wrap p-5 flex-col md:flex-row items-center">
                    <nav className="flex lg:w-2/5 flex-wrap items-center text-base md:ml-auto">
                        <a className="mr-5 hover:text-gray-900 cursor-pointer border-b border-transparent hover:border-indigo-600"></a>
                    </nav>
                    <a
                        className="flex order-first lg:order-none lg:w-1/5 title-font font-medium items-center lg:items-center lg:justify-center mb-4 md:mb-0">
                        <span className="ml-3 text-xl">L2 DEX HUB</span>
                    </a>
                    <div className="lg:w-2/5 inline-flex lg:justify-end ml-5 lg:ml-0">
                        <ConnectMetamaskButton Accounts={Accounts} onClick={() => { ConnectMetamask(); }}></ConnectMetamaskButton>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </header>
        </div>
    );
};
```

## fix

I fixed this line

```
import { useUserSigner } from "../../hooks/UserSigner";
```

to

```
import  useUserSigner  from "../../hooks/UserSigner";
```

then, error message was changed like this

```
Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
```

And it was pointing to this line in UserSigner

```
   const [signer, setSigner] = useState();
```

Should I change it to a function component?
I'm a React newbie and I don't know what the problem is!

Comment: How do you export `useUserSigner` function?

Comment: Yeah, I forgot copy the last line. I just edited it again.

Comment: I actually got the same error even if I exported like this (or not).

Answer (score 0):

proper placement of the hook should be like this:

```js
export default function ConnectWallet(props) {
  // ...
  // hook should be placed here
  const userSigner = useUserSigner(injectedProvider, ethersProvider);
  async function ConnectMetamask() {
    // placing any hook inside here won't work
    // because ConnectMetamask is NOT called when the component is being (re)rendered.
    // ...
  }
}
```

a functional component is rendered by calling the function that declares the component. Placing hooks(`useMemo, useState, etc...`) at functional component's scope allows them to recognize component's render timing. but when they are placed inside another function, which does not corresponds to render timing, they lose the capability to recognize the render timing. thus it fails to act as hook.

in other words, `useUserSinger` hook should be re-implemented and its usage should be also fixed.

```
import { useMemo, useState } from "react";

const useUserSigner = (injectedProvider, localProvider) => {
  const [signer, setSigner] = useState();
  useMemo(() => {
   // ... do something
  }, [])
  const doSomething = () => setSigner(/* ... */);
  return { doSomething }
}

function ConnectWallet(props) {
  // ...
  const { doSomething } = useUserSinger(injectedProvider, ethersProvider);
  // ...
  return <button onclick={doSomething} />
}
```

Comment: I did as you suggested, and the hook worked fine!
However, ``Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.
However, I got ``Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.

Comment: re-render has nothing to do with the placement or usage of hooks. re-render happens because you've possibly created loops inside of it. I am afraid to say this but at current state, your code is not very easy to follow, so it should be presented with reproducible snippets(implementing demo via glitch.io or codesandbox would be nice) so that I can try fixing it. For this question, please flag this as an answer and make another question with different title & the reproducible snippet. I've also always presented working demo in the answer when it's possible.

Comment: make sense! I have to go to work now, so I'll get back to you in a few hours! Sorry.